# Recursion confusion of list

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

Here's the problem

```
numberSet = [2,3,5], target number = 8
output -> [[2,2,2,2],[2,3,3],[3,5]]
```

And I think it can be solved by backtracking:

```
public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] candidates, int target) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new LinkedList<>();
    permutation(candidates, target, new LinkedList(), result);
    return result;
}

public void permutation(int[] candidates, int target, List<Integer> subresult, List<List<Integer>> result){
    if(target == 0){
        result.add(subresult);
        return;
    }
    for(int x: candidates){
        if(target - x >= 0){
            subresult.add(x);
            permutation(candidates, target - x, subresult, result);
            subresult.remove(subresult.size() - 1);
        }
    }
        return;
}
```

Everything makes sense to me, however, my output is:

```
[[],[],[],[]]
```

They are all empty list...
I want to figure out why so I print out each step when the condition

```
if(target == 0){
        result.add(subresult);
        System.out.println(result);
        return;
    }
```

is satisfied.
And I think my code do find the solution(even I haven't figured out how to remove those duplicates)

```
[[2, 2, 3]]
[[2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 2]]
[[3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2], [3, 2, 2]]
[[7], [7], [7], [7]]
```

Why would this happen??? Why is the result list still empty?
Thanks sooo much!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but since you're removing the last value of subresult- `subresult.remove(subresult.size() - 1);` in every recursive method call, and since result only adds a reference to the subresult, so every add/remove operation on the subresult would be changed in the result also.

In short-

If subresult is `[1,2,3]`
and you add this in result, then `result = [1,2,3]`

But now if you remove `3` from subresult, then result also becomes `[1,2]`

So in order to avoid that,

`result.add(new LinkedList<Integer>(subresult));`

This creates a new List object with the values of the passed in list.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The explanation is really helpful!